# I am not able to read the IEnumerable items in foreach loop

Tags: c#, asp.net, generics, ienumerable

I am trying to build a Events Calendar, where i am getting the dates/events from an XML file in C#

I am loading my xml document through this:

`XDocument myEventsDocument = XDocument.Load(Server.MapPath("Events.xml"));`

Then I am storing the events in a variable :

```
 var resultSet = from p in myEventsDocument.Descendants("event")
                    select new
                    {
                        eventName = p.Attribute("title").Value,
                        eventVenue = p.Attribute("venue").Value,
                        eventDate = p.Attribute("date").Value,
                        eventTime = p.Attribute("time").Value,
                        eventDuration = p.Attribute("LengthOfEventInMts").Value
                    };
```

Then I am caching the entire results:

```
 Cache.Insert("eventsCache", resultSet, new CacheDependency(Server.MapPath("Events.xml")));
```

In the DayRender event of the Calendar class, I am storing the Cached result in a non-generic collection of IEnumeration:

```
IEnumerable itemCache = (IEnumerable)Cache["eventsCache"];
```

When i loop through the items in itemCache, I am not seeing the items in intellisense, but when i step-over while debugging, i am seeing the IEnumerable items.

[image: screen shot in the code-behind]

[image: Here is the screen shot while stepping-through the code:]

Please help me out where i am going wrong.

Comment: Why don't you define a CalendarEvent class and use that instead of an anonymous type?

Comment: Thanks Andrew Kennan, i was able to achieve the solution from p.s.w.g by using 'dynamic' in the foreach loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike `IEnumerable<T>`, the `IEnumerable` interface does not assume the items being enumerated are of any particular type, so as far as intellisense is concerned, `myItem` is of type `object`. There are two options I see:

1. Use a named type rather than an anonymous type:

   ```
   public class MyCacheItem { ... }

   var resultSet = 
       from p in myEventsDocument.Descendants("event")
       select new MyCacheItem { ... }

   IEnumerable<MyCacheItem> itemCache = (IEnumerable<MyCacheItem>)Cache["eventCache"];
   ```
2. Use `dynamic` to iterate over the set. This won't give you intellisense, but it will allow your code to compile:

   ```
   foreach(dynamic myItem in itemCache)
   {
       ...
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks @p.s.w.g   I tried your solution of using 'dynamic' and worked well.  Learnt something new today.  Appreciate it.

Comment: @Ron Glad I could help. I would caution, however, that using `dynamic` is a little bit of a hack, and overusing it can have a significant performance impact and worse, make your code hard to maintain. There's nothing *wrong* with the solution, but I recommend you try the other solution first.

Comment: @Ron - `dynamic` is a powerful feature that can easily be misused. Make sure you carefully analyze whatever circumstances you are in each time before using it.

Comment: Thanks @p.s.w.g & ChaosPandion for the alert. Will keep that in mind, and use it accordingly.!! Much Thanks !!

Comment: @p.s.w.g i tried the 1st solution, using named type and works flawlessly.  & Thanks to ChaosPandian, as well, for suggesting similar solutions.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to create a simple class to access the members.

```
public sealed class EventInfo
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Venue { get; set; }
    public string Date { get; set; }
    public string Time { get; set; }
    public string Duration { get; set; }
}
```

Then you must evaluate the query.

```
var results = query.ToList().AsReadOnly();
Cache.Insert("eventsCache", results, 
    new CacheDependency(Server.MapPath("Events.xml")));
```

One you need the results you must cast to the proper type.

```
var itemCache = (IEnumerable<EventInfo>)Cache["eventsCache"];
```

Comment: Thanks ChaosPandion - I will keep this in mind for my future coding. I was able to achieve the results with less coding of implementing @p.s.w.g's solution of using 'dynamic'.  I appreciate your help.